# How to make a field unique ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I want to make Email field unique. It's a field of ApplicationUser (of IdentityUser) That's what I did : 
namespace BidProject.Models
{

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }


}
```

I have these references:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

I get these errors for that :

> The type or namespace name 'Index' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   The type or namespace
>   name 'IndexAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I make that field unique? Or can you tell me how IdentityUser's UserName field is unique? Thanks.

Comment: use  `[Index("IX_EmailUnique", 1, IsUnique = true)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

If that doesn't work, check if you have a reference to EntityFramework.dll.

Comment: The best way is using NuGet. Go to Solution Explorer, under your project, right-click on References, and select Manage NuGet Packages.

Comment: In my references in I can see EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer.. So I guess I have it

Comment: What's the version of your EntityFramework? Please click on EntityFramework under References, then check Version on the Properties pane.

Comment: It is 6.0.0.0 .Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a name for the Index. Use the below syntax.

```
[Index("IX_EmailUnique", 1, IsUnique = true)]
```

Comment: This is not working with EF6, it must be at least EF6.1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a namespace at the top of the file, or a project reference to EntityFramework.dll? Try putting your cursor inside the word 'Index', then hit ctrl-. -- you should see a popup menu offering something like 'resolve reference' or 'add using for using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;'

If you've got, say, a .net 4.0 project referencing a .net 4.5 assembly, sometimes that'll break things. You'll need to upgrade the project to a more recent version of the framework.

Comment: Ok. The compiler is telling you that it can't find the IndexAttribute class, so it's either (1) an incorrect namespace, or (2) you haven't got a project reference to the library (ef?) or (3) you've got, say, a .net 4.0 project referencing a .net 4.5 assembly: sometimes that'll break things

Comment: I think I satisfy all of the constraints. My project is .net 4.5. I have a reference to EF and namespace is correct.